# Using structure in a different .cpp files

Tags: c++, struct, include

I am trying to do use a structure and the function defining the structure in different files. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882637/using-struct-in-different-cpp-file) I am doing the following:

I define my `struct` and save it in the file `agent.h`

```
// File agent.h

#ifndef AGENT_H
#define AGENT_H
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// Define Nodes and Agents
struct Agent
{
    int home, work; // Locations
    int status; // S=0; E=1; I=2; R=3
    Agent *initialize_agents(int N, int V);
    Agent()
    {
        status = 0;
    }
}A;
#endif
```

I defined the function the function and saved it as `agent.cpp`

```
// File agent.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Agent.h"
using namespace std;
Agent *initialize_agents(int N, int V)
{
    Agent  *A = new Agent[N];
    char fileN[1024] =  "myFile.dat";
    FILE *f = fopen(fileN, "r"); // Binary File Home Work
    int k = 0;
    int v = 0;
    while (!feof(f))
    {
         int i, j;
         fscanf(f, "%d %d", &i, &j);
         A[k].home = i;
         A[k].work = j;
         k++;
    }
   return(A);
}
```

then I have the main file `main.cpp`

```
// File agent.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "agent.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int Inet;
    struct Agent;
    int V = 100;
    int N = 100;
    Agent *A = initialize_agents(N, V); // Initialize Agents
    return 0;
}
```

and I got the following error:

```
error: 'initialize_agents' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: declare `Agent *initialize_agents(int N, int V)` in the header file also.

Comment: And don't use `using namespace std;` in the header file.

Comment: There are several problems with this code. May I recommend you one of our [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn from?

Comment: And don't define a variable of type `Agent` in the header. Define the `struct` but not the variable at the end `}A;`.

Comment: @JoeyMallone Thank you

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thank you. I think I need it :-)

Comment: @JoeyMallone unfortunately I am still getting the same error. I modified the header file according to the comments as you can see now

Comment: Nope, now you have made it a member of the class. You really need to get into that book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code fixed to compile -

agent.h:

```
// File agent.h

#ifndef AGENT_H
#define AGENT_H
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// Define Nodes and Agents
struct Agent
{
    int home, work; // Locations
    int status; // S=0; E=1; I=2; R=3
    Agent()
    {
        status = 0;
    }
};

Agent *initialize_agents(int N, int V);
#endif
```

agent.cpp:

```
// File agent.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Agent.h"
using namespace std;
Agent *initialize_agents(int N, int V)
{
    Agent  *A = new Agent[N];
    char fileN[1024] = "myFile.dat";
    FILE *f = fopen(fileN, "r"); // Binary File Home Work
    int k = 0;
    int v = 0;
    while (!feof(f))
    {
        int i, j;
        fscanf(f, "%d %d", &i, &j);
        A[k].home = i;
        A[k].work = j;
        k++;
    }
    return(A);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
// File agent.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "agent.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int Inet;
    int V = 100;
    int N = 100;
    Agent *A = initialize_agents(N, V); // Initialize Agents
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It returns the following `error: cannot convert 'Agent*' to 'main()::Agent*' in initialization`

Comment: Are you sure you _don't_ use "struct Agent" in your main?

Comment: right I just removed it and it returns `/tmp/ccWik5Sx.o: In function 'main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x74c): undefined reference to 'initialize_agents(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: It seems you didn't include agent.cpp in your build.

Comment: I do have it in the same folder

Comment: Having it in the same folder is not enough. You need to compile it and link the output .obj file into the executable but that's already descibed under the link you refer to in the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188277/discussion-between-emax-and-marcin-zawiejski).