# How to make a simple structure visible in different cpp file

Tags: struct, c++17

I have a structure defined in main.cpp file and i want that same structure with value to be visible in other cpp file.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882637/using-struct-in-different-cpp-file) and [this is way out of understanding for me as a beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649234/using-structure-in-a-different-cpp-files). So i re-ask the [initial question again but in a simple way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882637/using-struct-in-different-cpp-file).

main.cpp

```cpp
#include<iostream>

extern struct abc
{
    int a;
    std::string bla_bla;
};

void display(abc (&)[2]);

int main(void)
{
    abc put[2];
    put[0] = {10,"Apple"};
    put[1] = {20,"Ball"};
    display(put);
}
```

other.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

extern abc;

void display(abc (&put)[2])
{
    std::cout << put[0].a << '\t' << put[0].bla_bla << std::endl;
    std::cout << put[1].a << '\t' << put[1].bla_bla << std::endl;
}
```

it shows error **a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions**
and i am using c++17
is there any way to make that one structure visible to every cpp?
thanks in advance

EDIT: I got it need to keep the struct in .h file

Comment: This is what *header files* and `#include` are for.

Comment: but header files will just make two different structs declared in different cpp files
and if i want contents of one struct in other will this method work?

Comment: nvm
thanks @Someprogrammerdude i just tried it

Comment: A structure is not an instance, there can only be "one" definition of a structure anyway no matter in how many [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) the structure is defined in.